# Google Sheets formula with variable number of disjoint columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In the table I have multiple disjoint columns with similar meaning: “is this row interesting?”

I want to create an array formula to get all interesting rows. How can I approach this?

Example table:

```
Obj id | Case 1 data | Case 1 interesting? | Case 2 data | Case 2 interesting?
     1 |       …     |        YES          |     …       |       NO
     2 |       …     |         NO          |     …       |       NO
     3 |       …     |         NO          |     …       |      YES
     4 |       …     |         NO          |     …       |       NO
     5 |       …     |        YES          |     …       |      YES
     6 |       …     |         NO          |     …       |       NO
```

The actual table is split into several sheets with different subsets of ids on each sheet.

My current approach is stuck with `INDIRECT` function not accepting array or ranges. I first search for my columns: `FILTER(COLUMN(A1:1), REGEXMATCH(A1:1, "interesting"))`, then I convert column addresses to ranges, but when I feed the result to `INDIRECT`, it only returns the first column.

The desired formula would output an array of unique object ids where each row is interesting for at least one case.

UPDATE: here is a [test table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rH3WpyUB1zA_bSsUeB8XWRj001wKcW0HHvQc6f2lWNY/edit?usp=sharing) for this problem. There are 3 sheets: student's data with ids and 2 programs. Each program has several exams (not known beforehand. The desired formula would output an array of unique student ids with at least 1 Passed exam (in the test sheet: 1, 3, 4, 6)

Comment: are interesting columns not on fixed/known position?

Comment: @player0 no, and their number keeps increasing as new cases are added

Comment: from your example, you want only row 5? or 1,3 and 5?

Comment: @player0 In this example: 1,3,5. I cannot share the original sheet, but I made a (hopefully) sufficient test example, please see the updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={"Passing"; ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(QUERY({
 IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE('Program 1'!A1:Z), , 999^99))), "Pass", "♠"), "♠"))="♠", 'Program 1'!A1:A, );
 IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE('Program 2'!A1:Z), , 999^99))), "Pass", "♠"), "♠"))="♠", 'Program 2'!A1:A, )},
 "where Col1 is not null order by Col1", 0)))}
```

[image: 0]

---

if you want to **`VLOOKUP`** it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, UNIQUE(QUERY({
 IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE('Program 1'!A1:Z), , 999^99))), "Pass", "♠"), "♠"))="♠", 'Program 1'!A1:A, );
 IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE('Program 2'!A1:Z), , 999^99))), "Pass", "♠"), "♠"))="♠", 'Program 2'!A1:A, )},
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)), 1, 0))<>"", "PASS", "FAIL"), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Do I get it right that here you're not looking for “Pass” in specific columns, but rather in the whole sheet? That works for me too, I just haven't thought about it

Comment: kind of. what I did was: I joined all columns into 1 column and converted all "Pass"es on spades and then regex out only one spade from each row. then convert back all spades to "PASS"  or to the corresponding ID